# Does moving a table to a separate datafile improve performance?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g, say that I have table A and table B both in the same datafile. Table A seldom has any updates while table B has lots of updates per second. I am having issues where the commits done by one process in Table A take some time to show up in queries done by other process. My theory is that by being in the same datafile, the activity on the datafile caused by table B will impact performance on queries and updates on Table A. Will commit performance improve on Table A if we move it to a separate datafile even if the datafile is in the same disk? I imagine that using a separate disk would be better, but I'd like to know whether a separate datafile in the same disk will still help.

I am particularly looking for answers that include good evidence (reference articles for example). Thanks!

Comment: Your theory isn't correct. Look at the concept of disk IO contention. It isn't about tables sharing datafiles its about datafiles sharing the same disk.

Comment: +1 mmmmmpie.  In ANY database, sharing the same I/O channel is a challenge.  Especially these days when everything is serial.  Oracle is no different.  If you are on a Linux machine run %iostat -x 1  This will show you just how hard the channel is getting hammered.